# How to open a csv file with .icloud extension

Tags: python, database, csv, datatable

Someone send me a CSV file with an additional.icloud extension, but does anyone know how to open this file either directly or in python? I've tried to open it up with both Windows and Mac, but neither works. I also tried to delete the ".icloud" extension, but then the CSV file got broken with only lines of messy codes left. Thanks for anyone who can help me out!!

The file is like the following:
[image]

Comment: do you have an icloud account, try uploading to an icloud account and converting to plain csv?

Answer (score 0):

Files with the ".icloud" extension aren't the original file, it just indicates that the file is available via your iCloud.

Turn off "Optimise Mac Storage" in your settings.
If this file was sent to you, ask the sender to resend the original copy.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS stores not yet downloaded files in format **.$FILENAME.icloud**. To force system to download it use this command:

```
brctl download final_df.csv
```

But be careful as it's downloading the files asynchronously.